# Is there an algebraic number of degree at least 3 such that the partial quotients on its continued fraction are bounded by any reasonable function?

Tags: number-theory, approximation, continued-fractions

Let $$2^{1/3}=a_0+\frac{1}{a_1+\dots}$$ be the canonical continued fraction of $2^{1/3}$. It is relatively easy to prove that if $a_n<10\phi^n$ then the equation $x^3-2y^3=1$ has no nontrivial integer solutions (this equation has no solutions anyway, but it would be an interesting alternative, and relatively easy, proof). The first few terms actually are:

$2^{1/3}= $[1; 3, 1, 5, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 8, 1, 14, 1, 10, 2, 1, 4, 12, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 14, 3, 12, 1, 15, 3, 1, 4, 534, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 121, 1, 2, 2, 4, 10, 3, 2, 2, 41, 1, 1, 1, 3, 7, 2, 2, 9, 4, 1, 3, 7, 6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 9, 3, 1, 1, 69, 4, 4, 5, 12, 1, 1, 5, 15, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 89, 1, 22, 186, 6, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 8, 9, 1, 26, 1, 7, 1, 18, 6, 1, 372, 3, 13, 1, 1, 14, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 9, 1, 6, 1, 38, 1, 2, 25, 1, 4, 2, 44, 1, 22, 2, 12, 11, 1, 1, 49, 2, 6, 8, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 9, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 27, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 36, 9, 13, 9, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 21, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 6, 2, 1, 6, 19, 1, 1, 18, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 27, 1, 1, 10, 3, 11, 38, 7, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 8, 1, 5, 1, 5, 4, 4, 4, 7, 2, 1, 21, 1, 1, 5, 10, 3, 1, 72, 6, 9, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 7, 8, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 8, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 30, 39, 2, 1, 3, 8, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 9, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 10, 1, 5, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 12, 2, 1, 8, 3, 2, 6, 1, 3, 10, 1, 2, 20, 1, 6, 1, 2, 186, 2, 2, 1, 2, 47, 1, 19, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 8, 1, 18, 3, 5, 39, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 1, 220, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 13, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 2, 1, 7, 1, 3, 1, 1, 11, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 33, 3, 1, 1, 2, 6, 3, 1, 1, 3, 6, 8, 3, 4, 84, 1, 1, 2, 1, 10, 2, 2, 20, 1, 3, 1, 7, 13, 14, 1, 29, 1, 1, 5, 1, 7, 1, 1, 2, 1, 56, 1, 3, 2, 1, 13, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 255, 2, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 71, 1, 9, 1, 2, 1, 11, 5, 1, 25, 1, 6, 67, 2, 9, 6, 1, 5, 2, 15, 1, 2, 48, 2, 7, 1, 3, 1, 4, 21, 1, 1, 2, 1, 27, 3, 26, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 3, 7451, 2, 29, 4, 3, 8, 17, 3, 8, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 113, 1, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 13, 1, 34, 1, 2, 7, 1, 3, 3, 7, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 69, 1, 3, 12, 34, 1, 2, 151, 1, 4941, 4, 1, 1, 12, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 6, 16, 1, 2, 27, 2, 13, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 11, 1, 1, 3, 1, 53, 2, 15, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 9, 1, 1, 10, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 10, 9, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 25, 16, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 13, 1, 49, 6, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 7, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 10, 5, 4, 8, 10, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 41, 1, 3, 1, 56, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5, 6, 6, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 12, 1, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 50, 5, 1, 2, 6, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 77, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 7, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 17, 1, 20, 7, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 31, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 1, 23, 20, 1, 22, 16, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 1, 1, 15, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 23, 6, 10, 3, 2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 10, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 108, 1, 1, 11, 2, 6, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 9, 3, 1, 1, 3, 22, 4, 1, 93, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 11, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 28, 23, 4, 11, 1, 9, 1, 4, 3, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 12, 2, 6, 19, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 1, 43, 1, 1, 5, 1, 73, 6, 35, 5, 4, 1, 13, 2, 1, 6, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 27, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 14, 9, 14, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 3, 3, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 20, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 11, 1, 1, 14, 1, 1, 14, 1, 9, 1, 1, 1, 33, 2, 1, 3, 7, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 27, 1, 1, 2, 34, 2, 1, 8, 6, 4, 1, 1, 7, 1, 5, 3, 1, 354, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 6, 1, 1, 3, 17, 1, 3, 1, 195, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 25, 1, 3, 1, 2, 304, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 9, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 44, 1, 1, 1, 2, 8, 16, 1, 204, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 20, 1, 11, 1, 8, 1, 2, 16, 1, 1, 1, 10, 5, 1, 10, 6, 1, 5, 2, 1, 33, 6, 6, 1, 3, 1, 1, 28, 1, 10, 3, 1, 1, 23, 2, 2, 1, 7, 4, 1, 4, 1, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 7, 1, 5, 201, 6, 1, 10, 8, 9, 1, 3, 3, 8, 5, 1, 136, 1, 2, 6, 2, 1, 2, 2, 9, 1, 4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 29, 1, 1, 4, 12, 1, 6, 4, 1, 13, 1, 2, 1, 2, 6, 127, 2, 2, 1, 1, 119, 1, 124, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 10, 1, 9, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 8, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 8, 1, 4, 3, 2, 8, 3, 1, 3, 1, 6, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 4, 4, 9, 2, 3, 16, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 16, 1, 4, 2, 1, 10, 1, 4, 1, 2, 6, 4, 1, 5, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 11, 1, 2, 23, 1, 7, 11, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 49, 8, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 8, 1, 9, 3, 9, 1, 1, 5, 23, 5, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 90, 2, 1, 5, 56, 1, 2, 3, 1, 8, 85, 1, 1, 131, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 37, 1, 14, 1, 5, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 11, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 52, 18, 4, 7, 2, 101, 2, 1, 119, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 13, 3, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 27, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 11, 1, 5, 3, 1, 9, 1, 1, 15, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 15, 2, 1, 2, 7, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 23, 1, 1, 19, 1, 5, 12, 3, 5, 1, 1, 10, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 22, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 36, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 10, 1, 14, 6, 1, 5, 2, 1, 328, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 11, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 2, 16, 2...]

More [here](http://pastebin.com/uwzf0dpc).

So if we have an even weak upper bound on the coefficients on the continued fraction of an algebraic number we can solve lots of diophantine equations using approximation arguments. I think even something ridiculous like $$\alpha=[a_0;a_1\dots]\implies a_n < e^{e^{e^n}}$$ for some known algebraic $\alpha$ might prove useful. It looks like such a statement should be easy to prove but unfortunately I don't have anything so far.

Comment: I would not expect there to be anything easier than the references Keith Conrad gave. Still, I recommend the inexpensive http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/number-theory/neverending-fractions-introduction-continued-fractions  to purchase or borrow.

Comment: @WillJagy, the diophantine equation is only the motivation for the question.

Comment: I see; you intend $\phi = ( 1 + \sqrt 5) / 2.$  I would like to see your proof of the implication.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth's_theorem

Comment: @WillJagy If $x=[a_0;a_1\dots]$ and $p_n/q_n=[a_0;a_1\dots a_n]$ then $\left|x-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right|>\frac{1}{(a_{n+1}+2)q_n^2}$, and if $x^2-2y^3=1$ then $0<\frac{x}{y}-2^{1/3}<\frac{1}{2^{2/3}3y^3}$ and by the recurrence relation of the convergents of the continued fraction, $q_n\geq F_n$ where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number. Then use Binet's formula.

Comment: I think we usually go the other direction. We have bounds on rational approximations to $\root3\of2$ and other algebraic numbers (Liouville, Roth, Baker), and from those we deduce bounds on the partial quotients of the continued fraction.